# When i refresh the browser and any page, my ngx countdown is resets, so how to make it not reset on page refresh in angular?

Tags: php, angularjs, wordpress

```
<countdown id="countdown" [config]="{leftTime: 10}" (event)="onTimerFinished($event)"  class="fa fa-clock-o"></countdown>
```

this is my countdown HTML please tell me how I can do.

Comment: When you refresh the page AngularJS is restarted. Refresh is one of many ways to reset your counter, everything running on browser can be hacked by an experient user. If you want to be sure that counter is not reseted you should control it on server side.

Comment: @MariaGabriela thanks for the response but my requirement is in angular side  I am not using any server-side language

Comment: Check browser persistence like Cookies, LocalStorage, SessionStorage

Answer (score 0):

You could use sessionStorage to store the state of the countdown.
SessionStorage: The sessionStorage property allows you to access a session Storage object for the current origin. A page session lasts for as long as the browser is open and survives over page reloads and restores. 
Get the leftTime from sessionStorage and set it when an event occurs.

```js
vm.timeLeft = sessionStorage.getItem('countDownLeftTime') || 0
```